# How to implement a JSON that contains a variable from another method in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, class, methods

I want to implement a JSON string in Scala that looks like the following in the method toJSON: ""{"gold": gold, "time": old_time}"". Old_time is the variable that I want to take from the method update. How do I do this?

```
class Click{
    val gold = 10
def update(time: Double): Double = {
    val old_time = time
    val faster = old_time * 2
    faster
    }
def toJSON(): String = {
    ""{"gold": gold, "time": old_time}""
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to print new time in `toJSON` or what was the argument value of the `update` method?

Comment: you really need to start accept the answers on your questions

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :)

```
class Click(v: Double) {
  val gold = 10

  def update(time: Double): Double = {
    val old_time = time
    val faster = old_time * 2
    faster
  }

  def toJSON(): String = {
    s"""{"gold": $gold, "time": ${update(v)}}"""
  }
}
```

Comment: how does it answer the question?